# Generate 6 different numbers from 1 to 10 in Java

Tags: java

I wrote down my code at first and then it cannot ensure that it is 6 different number.

```
public class JavaTest{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] list = new int[6];
    int number = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        list[i] = number;
        number = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        for (int j = 1; j < i; j++){
            number = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            if (number == list[j])
                number = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
    }
}
}
```

I think something wrong with my inner for loop j, but I don't know how to improve it. Can anyone help me modify it? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 9):

You could possibly do something like:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

And then take the 6 first numbers.

Without using collections:

```
int[] list = new int[6];
boolean[] used = new boolean[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    int number = (int) ((10 - i) * Math.random());
    for (int a = 0; a <= number; a++) {
        if (used[a]) {
            number++;
        }
    }
    list[i] = number + 1;
    used[number] = true;
}
```

Comment: Actually I know how to solve it in this way, but I just want to try another way to solve it. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @yolam Added a version without collections. Edit: Actually it's not completely random. I'll edit it.

Comment: Fixed, should be fine now.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use Set. Set will ensure that there will be 6 different numbers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
    Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>(6);

    while (numbers.size() < 6) {
        numbers.add(1 + random.nextInt(10));
    }

    System.out.println(numbers);
}
```

Comment: Set does not keep an order of the added elements. He could as well just go ahead and add numbers from 1 to 6 to produce the effect like you provided.

Comment: Task was to generate 6 different numbers, any word about their order.

Comment: I am just a beginner and cannot understand Set now, sorry. I will find materials related to Set later and thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

    Random rand = new Random();

    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

   return randomNum;
}
```

Source: [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java/363692#363692)